What are the appropriate data splitting techniques for time-dependent sequential datasets, such as breakdown records over time?
I am working with a time-dependent sequential dataset, specifically a record of machine breakdowns over a period of time. My dataset includes data from the sensors of several machines until they fail and need to be prepared; after the reparation, the machine sends data again. I want to develop a Machine Learning model to predict the remaining useful life from this data.
I understand that using a random split of the dataset into training, validation, and test sets may lead to overfitting issues, as there might be common data points in both the training and test sets if the split doesn't respect the temporal order of events.
Given the time-dependent nature of my data, what are the most appropriate techniques for splitting the dataset to ensure that my model generalizes well to unseen data? I have thought about dividing the dataset

according to the machine, keeping some of them for each dataset.
according to the period, keeping some periods between the reparation and the breakdown for each dataset.

However, are there standard techniques for data division in these kind of situations?

Speaking in general, data splitting is inefficient (vs. resampling) and when there is a long-term time-trend, splitting on time can result in inaccurate predictions that would have been easily solved by modeling all the data and included a flexible nonlinear time trend.
